# Split string based on certain logic in psql

Tags: postgresql, split

I have some strings that look like this:

```
'george hughes and steve jones'
```

And I am wanting to split this up in to two strings. I am doing this by:

```
select regexp_split_to_table('george hughes and steve jones and dennis lowe',' and ') into names;
```

Which returns `george hughes` and `steve jones` and `dennis lowe`.

However, I also have some strings that look like this:

```
'john and mark jackson'
```

These two people have the same surname but using the above function would return `john` and `mark jackson` as opposed to `john jackson` and `mark jackson`

Is there any way I can apply some logic to the regexp function and if the split word (in this case ' and ' only has one word then to use some different functionality?

This would allow the first example to still work, but the second example will split to `john jackson` and `mark jackson` as I will use another function that will likely apend the last word in the full string (`jackson`) to the broken down sections that contain one word only (`john`).

Comment: How would you know whether to borrow the other person's last name (`madonna and sean penn`, `mary anne and john smith`), or what even constitutes a last name (`john smith and mary anne von der heide`)?

Comment: It won't be a catch-all solution but it will be better than what I have at the minute which treats the entire string as one name. In your examples (edge cases), I'd be happy with ```madonna penn``` and ```mary anne```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following, which fills in any missing surnames:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
  'tim price and neil and adam sutcliffe and clive johnson and john and mark jackson',
  '(?<=^| and )(\w+?) and (\w+?) (?!and )(\w+?)(?=$| )',
  '\1 \3 and \2 \3',
  'g'
);
```

This returns:

```
                                           regexp_replace                                            
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 tim price and neil sutcliffe and adam sutcliffe and clive johnson and john jackson and mark jackson
(1 row)
```

This looks for a word followed by ' and ', followed by another word, followed by a word that isn't 'and ' followed by either the end of the text or another space, then adds in the surname from the second name after the first name.  The 'g' is a global flag meaning it'll keep going after the first substitution.

You could then split this by your original method.

Comment: This looks close to a solution but doesn't seem to work with just two names, for example ```'gary smith and hilary jones'```

Comment: The above code with this line doesn't work as expected ```'tim price and neil and adam sutcliffe and clive johnson and john and mark jackson and gary smith and hilary jones'```

Comment: Oh, forgot to add in the look-behind.  I've edited the example and it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the complex regex:

```sql
select    name.f
       || ' '
       -- If no last name, use the next one in the list
       || coalesce(nullif(name.l,''),lead(name.l) over ())
          as full_name
from regexp_split_to_table('tim price and neil and adam sutcliffe and clive johnson and john and mark jackson',' and ') list(name)

     -- Find the position of the space separating first and last name.  If no last name, set to one char past first name
     join lateral (select coalesce(nullif(position(' ' in list.name),0),char_length(list.name)+1)) delim(pos) on true

     -- Return first and last names separately
     join lateral (
    select left(list.name,delim.pos-1)
          ,overlay(list.name placing '' from 1 for delim.pos)
     ) name(f,l) on true
;
```

Returns:

```
   full_name    
----------------
 tim price
 neil sutcliffe
 adam sutcliffe
 clive johnson
 john jackson
 mark jackson
(6 rows)
```